# What function is passed to cb here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, asynccallback

So I have a small project containing both frontend (html) and backend (express: server, routers) parts. The project isn't that clean, so the its main operationality is launched directly in html  section. And not much is clear to me here, especially **what function is passed to cb** (callback) here?

I have the following code in  part of my html page within js project:

```
            const $ = document.getElementById.bind(document)

            const request = (path, cb) =>
                fetch(path)
                    .then((res) => {
                        if (res.ok) return res.json()
                        throw Error('HTTP error: ' + res.status)
                    })
                    .then(cb)
                    .catch((err) => ($('result').innerHTML = err))

            const main = async () => {
                const pinRequired = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search).get('pin')
                const id = await request(`./qrcode?pin=${pinRequired}`, (json) => {
                    const { qrbase64, deeplink, pin, id } = json
                    $('qrcode').innerHTML = `<img src="${qrbase64}" alt="Red dot" />`
                    $('deeplink').innerHTML = `<a href=${deeplink} target="_blank"> ${deeplink.slice(0, 90)}...</a>`
                    $('pin').innerHTML = pin ? pin : 'Not requested'
                    return id
                })

                setInterval(() => request(`./status?id=${id}`, ({ status }) => ($('result').innerHTML = status)), 1000)
            }

            main().catch(console.log)
```

Is this (json)? I also don't know why it is in () round brackets, however, it is an object, it cannot be passed as a callback, right?

And I also have a code in another file, which contains /qrcode route of my website. There is a function (quite big, so i'm not posting it, just pointing that it doesn't return function that may be passed as a callback).

If this callback 100% is in another part of the code, as you think, please let me know.

Comment: Look up what an `arrow` function is in Javascript.  That's what `(json) => { ... }` is.  Also, the `await` in front of your call to `request()` isn't doing anything useful.  You should either be using a callback design OR a promise design, not both mixed together.  In general, the future of the language is a promise-design so that's where you should be headed using only promises for control flow, not plain callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking about is this callback `(json) => { ... }` in the code below:

```
               request(`./qrcode?pin=${pinRequired}`, (json) => {
                    const { qrbase64, deeplink, pin, id } = json
                    $('qrcode').innerHTML = `<img src="${qrbase64}" alt="Red dot" />`
                    $('deeplink').innerHTML = `<a href=${deeplink} target="_blank"> ${deeplink.slice(0, 90)}...</a>`
                    $('pin').innerHTML = pin ? pin : 'Not requested'
                    return id
                });
```

Then this is what is known as an **arrow function**.  You can read about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on MDN.  They are a shortcut syntax for declaring a function that also has a number of implementation differences.

Note, there are some other issues in your code as `request()` does not return a promise so it does no good to use `await` on it and you won't get the `id` back from `return id` either.

Also note that the request library has been deprecated and generally shouldn't be used for new code.  There is a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143), all of which support promises natively.  My favorite in that list is the [`got()` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).